# How to inline display file input?

Tags: html, css

How do I set multiple file input on the same line ? Like radio-inline sets radio buttons on the same line. Is there any way to do this for file input ?

```css
input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}
.custom-file-upload {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class = "form-inline">
  <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Custom Upload
  </label>
  <input id="file-upload" type="file"/> 
</div>

<div class = "form-inline">
  <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Custom Upload
  </label>
  <input id="file-upload" type="file"/> 
</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean horizontal line? Because they are already on the same line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `inline-block` on form-inline.

```css
input[type="file"] {
    display: none;
}
.custom-file-upload {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.form-inline{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class = "form-inline">
    <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Custom Upload
    </label>
     <input id="file-upload" type="file"/> 
</div>
                    
<div class = "form-inline">
    <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Custom Upload
    </label>
     <input id="file-upload" type="file"/> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Cover both of those inputs withing single div tag with class form-inline. 
Do you mean something like this. Check your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q90whcau/3/). Its updated. --

```
<div class = "form-inline">
    <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> File1
    </label>
     <input id="file-upload" type="file"/> 

    <label for="file-upload" class="custom-file-upload">
    <i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> File1
    </label>
     <input id="file-upload" type="file"/> 
</div>
```

Comment: That worked but i don't know why people downvoted this

Comment: @NaveenKumar I'm glad it helped you out. Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

Juste add display "inline-block" to div with class "form-inline" :

```
.form-inline {
  display:inline-block;
}
```

I belive it should do the job.

EDIT: too late ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can give the container `.form-inline` the `display:inline-block;` property.
Hope i got your question right.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to FreeKrishna's answer, you can

```
float:left
```

in css and leave the divs as is.